# MySQL and the ST_IsValid function returns error

Tags: postgis, geojson, mysql, epsg

I am running MySQL // [Percona 5.7](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-server) and I added a Polygon to my table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table`;
CREATE TABLE `test_table` (`uid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`geom` geometry NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`uid`), SPATIAL KEY `i_geomidx` (`geom`) );
INSERT INTO `test_table` (`uid`, `geom`) VALUES ('1',ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{"type": "FeatureCollection","features": [{"type": "Feature","properties": {},"geometry": {"type": "Polygon","coordinates": [[[-91.2,45.4],[-79.8,49.8],[-69.0,43.4],[-88.2,32.6],[-91.2,45.4]]]}}]}',1,4326));
SELECT uid FROM test_table  WHERE ( St_intersects(geom,St_geomfromGeoJSON('{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-80.8,43.7], "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}}',1,4326)));
SELECT St_IsValid(geom) FROM test_table;
```

The first test with the intersect works like a charm but the ST_IsValid function returns the error:

```
ERROR 1210 (HY000): Incorrect arguments to st_isvalid
```

But the [MySQL help states](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-isvalid):

```
SET @ls1 = ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0)');
SELECT ST_IsValid(@ls1);
```

Any ideas someone?

Comment: What does PostGIS have to do with this? It is tagged PostGIS.

Comment: What does it return if you actually check using a valid linestring -- which a single point is not? I believe MySQL is objecting to the function ST_GeomFromText not the ST_IsValid. Postgis behaves the same. I believe the behavoir of MySQL is correct, but the docs are not.

Comment: Postgis, for what it is worth, returns ERROR:  geometry requires more points
HINT:  "LINESTRING(0 0)" <-- parse error at position 16 within geometry to `select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0)');` I don't have a MySQL install to check against any more, but this suggests that MySQL has correctly implemented the standard.

Comment: @JohnBarça, you're about right that LINESTRING(0 0) is not a valid geometry. Yet I used this example to demonstrate the the argument to ST_isvalid might not be wrong at all.

Comment: What does `select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0)');` return. And what about `select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)')`? That is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL version 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html) says:

> ST_IsValid() works only for the Cartesian coordinate system and
>   requires a geometry argument with an SRID of 0.

The geometries you created use an SRID of 4326.

The behaviour changed for [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html).